# SonarQube scan does not report all the issues to dashbaord

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Following is the content of `sonar-project.properties`

```
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
sonar.exclusions=**/src/test/**/*,**/src/**/*.xml,**/target/**/*.js
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco.exec
sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=target/jacoco-report/jacoco.xml
sonar.junit.reportPaths=target/surefire-reports
sonar.qualitygate.wait=true
sonar.tests=src/test
sonar.sources=src/main/
sonar.projectBaseDir: "src/"
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname.org.com:1521:ORCLDB
sonar.scm.exclusions.disabled=true
```

However sonar scan does not report all the reports to the sonarqube dashboard. I could see the `Bugs`, `Vulnerabilities`, `Security HotSpots`, `Debt` and `Code Smells` in `IntelliJ` IDE using SOnarqube plugin.

What kind of configuration is missing here?

[image]